# Trouble with jQuery selector possibly related to AngularJS

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs

I am displaying this third-party web page inside an Android webview in our app. I'd like to execute some javascript to automate the login, since the app knows the credentials for the third-party site.

https://qs-beta.emfit.com/#!/user/presence

The problem is that I can not select the elements I need. There is a div with id="login" that I can see with $("#login"). However, no luck with the input elements I need to work with:

$("#checkbox"), $("#username") nor $("#password")

The only thing I can think of is some problem with the way AngularJS lays out the DOM.

The code:

```
btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String js = "javascript:(function () {" +
                "return $(\"#username\").length;" +  //returns 0. $("#login").length returns 1
                "})()";
        wvBrowser.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                Log.d("", s);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

When I examine the DOM, via the Javascript console of my desktop browser, I see the missing elements. When I do so from Android using chrome://inspect to examine the webview's contents, they doe not appear. And that gets initiated from a button I can press after the page is loaded so I know the page is fully rendered. It's almost like the webview does not maintain a complete picture of the DOM.

My simple test code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wvBrowser;
    Button btnCheck;
    Activity theActivity;

    String url = "https://qs-beta.emfit.com/#!/user/presence";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        theActivity = this;

        btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
        wvBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        wvBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wvBrowser.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        wvBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("Test", "Page finished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(theActivity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        wvBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                //Required functionality here
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }
        });

        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String js = "javascript:(function () {" +
                        "return $(\"#checkbox\").html();" +
                        "})()";
                //js = "javascript:return $('#login').length";  //works

                wvBrowser.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        Log.d("", s);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        // TODO add parameters here
        String params = String.format("");
        try {
            params = URLEncoder.encode(params, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Test", "Program error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        wvBrowser.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general practice, mixing jQuery and Angular rarely plays out well in the end.  It would be much better if you automated this with an Angular component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you evaluate `$("#username").length` in the browser, you'll see that you correctly get `1` as the result.

I expect that what is probably happening is that you're running the JavaScript via android before the whole of the angular page is loaded. Parts of the page are loaded dynamically, so you won't be able to make use of the usual browser events for page load being completed.

I see that you have both an `ng-view` and `ng-include` in the code, both of which may fetch more dynamically inserted DOM after the page has "finished" loading, and the login form is inside one of these.

You could do a quick and dirty sanity check here by delaying the code you run, but a more robust long-term approach would be for the web page to communicate to android through a JavaScript interface once the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks Ed! Interesting. When I examine the DOM like you do, in the Javascript console of my desktop browser, I get the same result. When I do so from Android in the debugger, I get 0. And that gets initiated from a button I can press after the page is loaded so I know the page is fully rendered. It's almost like the webview does not maintain a complete picture of the DOM.

Comment: That's interesting, I will try it remotely on an android device on Monday if you still haven't solved it.

Comment: Cool! I added some more information in the question and the code I'm using.

Comment: Having checked this on my android device, it also works - as such I think it must be a problem specific to your device (or more accurately the WebView version it has), which device are you using?

Comment: Interesting. Samsung SM-T320 tablet with Android 4.4.2. It's the target for this project. Did you use the code I posted? I searched for possible reported webview bugs in this area and found none.  I wonder if there is so additional Javascript I could add that would entice the webview to update the rendering of the DOM it reports.

Comment: I didn't use any of the android code you posted,  just the jQuery selector running in the device's browser console (using chrome://inspect) . Just realised this isn't necessarily the same as a webview in an app on earlier versions of android.

Comment: Thanks Ed. For some reason, I'm now able to manipulate the page as desired. I think the owner may have fixed something. Once the form is submitted there is another problem on the server  (always something!), but I'm passed this. The suggestion of delaying the form fill attempt was very helpful!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!